# More efficient way to update an element in a list in Elm?

Tags: list, elm

Is there a more efficient way to update an element in a list in Elm than `map`ing over each element?

```
{ model | items = List.indexedMap (\i x -> if i == 2 then "z" else x) model.items }
```

Maybe Elm's compiler is sophisticated enough to optimize this so that `map` or `indexedMap` isn't unnecessarily copying over every element except 1. What about nested lists?

[Clojure has `assoc-in`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc-in) to update an element inside a nested list or record (can be combined too). Does Elm have an equivalent?

Comment: Maybe you can use a `Dict` instead of a `List`. It really depends on what you're modeling with the list.

Comment: @Emmanuel, modeling an ordered list of items.

Comment: In this case a (balanced) tree could be a more efficient data-structure for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More efficient in terms of **amount of code** would be (this is similar to @MichaelKohl's answer):

```
List.take n list ++ newN :: List.drop (n+1) list
```

*PS: if n is < 0 or n > (length of list - 1) then the new item will be added before or at the end of the list.*

*PPS: I seem to recall that `a :: alist` is slightly better performing than `[a] ++ alist`.*

If you mean efficient in terms of **performance**/ number of operations:

As soon as your lists get large, it is more efficient to use an `Array` (or a `Dict`) instead of a List as your type.

But there is a trade-off:

- `Array` and `Dict` are very efficient/ performant when you frequently retrieve/ update/ add items.
- `List` is very performant when you do frequent sorting and filtering and other operations where you actually need to map over the entire set.

That is why in my code, `List` is what I use a lot in `view` code. On the data side (in my `update` functions) I use `Dict` and `Array` more.

Comment: So would it be best then to store the model as a List and when you need to update a single element (say by index) you would to `list |> Array.fromList |> Array.set n newN |> Array.toList` instead of `List.take n list ++ newN :: List.drop (n+1) list` ?

Comment: Not quite. If most operations you expect are on all items: then store as a List. If most (> 50%) of expected operations are on single item: then use a Dict. If a List turns out to be preferred, then do the simple (less code) List update. For updating a single item, it is probably not efficient for convert a list to a Dict (or Array), then update item, then convert to List again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not overly familiar with Elm, but given that it's immutable by default, I'd assume it uses structural sharing for its underlying data structures, so your concern re memory may be unfounded.

Personally I think there's nothing wrong with your approach posted above, but if you don't like it, you can try something like this (or `List.concat`):

```
List.take n list ++ newN :: List.drop (n+1)
```

Comment: Structural sharing occurs when you can tell the compiler that you only want to change part of a data structure. Otherwise the compiler has to infer that's what you're trying to do and optimize accordingly. What I was saying was that I'm not sure that Elm's compiler will infer this from my `map` operation. If Elm's compiler is able to, then can it optimize nested lists too? Regardless, it seems like there should be a more elegant mechanism. Your way is an alternative approach too, but I was hoping for more of an `assoc-in`

Comment: Fair point. Like I said, I'm not really familiar with Elm, so I'm not 100% sure, thought it seems like it should be able to infer it from your code. From reading the docs I could find nothing like `assoc-in` and most people seem to use a form similar to yours. I really just added mine as more terser way. I think you should just pick what reads best to you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, an Elm list is not meant for such a use-case. Instead, consider using an [Array](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/Array). `Array` contains a `set` function you can use for what is *conceptually* an in-pace update. Here's an example:

```
import Html exposing (text)
import Array

type alias Model = { items : Array.Array String }

model =
  { items = Array.fromList ["a", "b", "c"]
  }

main =
  let 
    m = { model | items = Array.set 2 "z" model.items }
    z = Array.get 2 m.items
    output = case z of
      Just n -> n
      Nothing -> "Nothing"
  in
    text output -- The output will be "z"
```

If for some reason you need `model.items` to be a `List`, note that you can convert back and forth between `Array` and `List`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely not an Elm expert, but a look at Elm's [List](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/List) documentation did not reveal any function to update the element at a given index in a list.

I like [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40733516/440294).  It's quite elegant.  If you prefer a less-elegant, recursive approach, you can do something like the following.  (Like I said, I'm not an Elm expert, but hopefully the intention of the code is clear if its not quite right.  Also, I don't do any error handling.)

```
updateListAt :: List a -> Int -> a -> List a
updateListAt (head :: tail) 0 x = x :: tail
updateListAt (head :: tail) i x = head :: (updateListAt tail (i - 1) x)
```

However, both the runtime and space complexity will be O(n) in both the average and worst cases, regardless of the method used.  This is a consequence of Elm's `List` being a single-linked list.

Regarding `assoc-in`, if you look at the Clojure source, you'll see that `assoc-in` is just recursively defined in terms of `assoc`.  However, I think you'd have trouble typing it for arbitrary, dynamic depth in Elm.